# Let $x= \frac{a}{b} (a\neq b , b\neq 0)$ express $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ in terms of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This exercise appears in a AoPS introduction to algebra book and it says:

> Let $x= \frac{a}{b} (a\neq b , b\neq 0)$ express $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ in terms of $x$.

I am not able to understand the hint book gives me:

> We need to get an $x$ into the fraction. Solve the equation involving $x$ for $a$ in terms of $x$ and $b$. How can you use the result with the fraction you need to express in terms of $x$?

My question are

1. What does it means with "get a $x$ into the fraction? is it like adding 0 or multiplying by 1?
2. What equation I am supposed to solve? If I make appear a $x$ into the fraction What should I equal that expression to turn it into a equation?

Comment: Hint: Rearrange the fraction to get $a=xb$. What can you do with this and $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$?

Comment: By "get a $x$ into the fraction", the book means to substitute $a$ in terms of $x$ and $b$ into the fraction $\frac {a+b}{a-b}$. Doing so will allow you to find $\frac {a+b}{a-b}$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: We have $$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{\frac{a+b}{b}}{\frac{a-b}{b}}$$

Answer (score 4):

What it essentially is asking is to write $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ in an equivalent form with only $x$ as a variable. So your primary goal when 'transforming' $\frac{a+b}{a-b}$ is to find a way to write it with a bunch of $\frac{a}{b}$'s. So you can write the following (using the hint in the comments):

$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{\frac{a+b}{b}}{\frac{a-b}{b}}=\frac{\frac{a}{b}+1}{\frac{a}{b}-1}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$

So once you've solved this you can equate the two equivalent expressions in an equation $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$. Hence you've not really solved an equation, but rather 'created' an equation.

With the hint the book gives, it tries to hint at writing $\frac{a}{b}=x\Leftrightarrow a=bx$. Then you can write

$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{bx+b}{bx-b}=\frac{b(x+1)}{b(x-1)}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$$ which may or may not be faster depending on what method you prefer. Note that once again you get the equation $\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$.